# Can I use simple HTML for @ManagedBean?

Tags: java, html, web-services, web, managed-bean

I am studying Managed Beans right now. I need to use html file to get the data and post them on the next page. I need to use ManagedBean. I am required to use .html file. I can't use JSF because we haven't began to study it yet.

Question: How can I set the value first name in the Voter.java class and then post it the new page?

I tried to use:

```
 First Name:<input action="UserInfo.setFirstName()" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="30"  
       value="" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,30}" title="Please enter first name! Min 1 
       letter"required/><br>
```

but it doesn't work after I deploy the program.

welcome.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
    <form action="summary.html">
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Form:</legend>
       <fieldset>
       <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
   First Name:<input action="UserInfo.setFirstName()" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="30"  
       value="" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,30}" title="Please enter first name! Min 1 
       letter"required/><br>
       </fieldset>
       <p></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

summary.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Thank you</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>Information Summary</h1>
        <li action="SubmissionController.getFirstName()"><b>First Name:</b>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="userinfo")
@SessionScoped
public class UserInfo {

   private String fname;

   public UserInfo() {}

   public String getFirstName() {
     return fname;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String fname) {
      this.fname = fname;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to find any example with .html file and @ManagedBean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is yes I can use simple HTML with ManagedBeans. 
I just used Java Servlets, HTML and CDI managed beans. I had to use @Inject the reference of class type where is the bean and I used it in the class where I use Servlets. In the bean class I used Named and SessionScoped beans. So the beans store the info that is submitted by the user.